# Shell Script, commandline arguments

Tags: linux, shell

the task is to write a shell script
inputs are a string and a number

for example,

xxx.sh "Hello World" 3

the input will be

```
***************
* Hello World *
* Hello World *
* Hello World *
***************
```

and here is what have I got so far:

```
function mantra()   {
    echo "string is $1"
    echo "number is $2"

    echo $string
    echo $PATH
    for num in string_length; do
        echo "*"
    done
}
```

How do I count the number of characters in the string?
Am I doing right? I am not exactly sure how to pass command-line arguments into my function.Blockquote

Answer (score 1):

The number of characters in your input string is `${#1}`

See [this](http://linuxgazette.net/108/park.html) page for a short explanation.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/bin/sh

function mantra()   {

    string=$1
    num=$2

    strlen=${#string}

    let strlen=$strlen+2


    echo -n "*"
    for (( times = 0; times < $strlen; times++ )); do echo -n "*" ; done

    echo "*";


}

mantra $1 $2

    for (( times = 0; times < $num; times++ )); do
        echo "* $string *"
    done

mantra $1 $2
```